# Titanium Studio: Target Android SDK 11 is not installed

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

I am using titanium studio and attempting to run the application (kitchen sink) on a galaxy nexus phone. The phone shows up in the studio, however when I build I get the following error:

[ERROR] :  Target Android SDK 11 is not installed
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

when I try to run it in the emulator I get a similar error:

[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
[ERROR] :  Target Android SDK 11 is not installed

I have been researching for awhile and I cannot seem to find a solution to fix this problem.
Any help would be appreciated (I am a student so detailed instructions are really helpful)

Thank You

-Jim

Comment: As the error message clearly indicates you haven't installed Android SDK (API-11). To resolve the error Open Android SDK manager and install Android 3.0(HoneyComb)

Answer (score 0):

You might have this defined in your tiapp.xml

```
<tool-api-level>11</tool-api-level>
```

Change it to android api level you have installed. I guess for android 4.0 and above is >= 15. Not sure.